# Downscaling drawables at runtime?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm developing a launcher app, which accesses app icons as Drawable objects. A few apps are affecting the responsiveness (scrolling stutters), and I think it's due to their app icons being a high resolution (the primary offender is LibreTube). So I'm considering downscaling and caching the icons to improve performance.

Any attempt to search for this only results in answers during development time, or resizing image files. I need to scale a Drawable object (or resample it) during runtime.

Comment: You can convert drawable to bitmap and use it. This is very resource saving.